# How can I replace the content of a panel with new content?

Tags: extjs

I have a `regionContent` panel which I add to my viewport.

**How can I replace its content with new content?**

```
    ...
    var regionContent = new Ext.Panel({
        id: 'contentArea',
        region: 'center',
        padding:'10',
        autoScroll: true,
        html: 'this is the original content'
    });

    var viewport = new Ext.Viewport({
        layout: 'border',
        items: [ regionMenu, regionContent ]
    });

    var newPanel = new Ext.Panel({
        region: 'east',
        title: 'Info Panel',
        width: 300,
        html: 'this is a panel that is added'
    });
    // regionContent.update(newPanel); //renders as javascript code ???
    // regionContent.remove(...) //how do I remove ALL CONTENT, I will not know what is in this panel to remove it specifically
    regionContent.add(newPanel); //adds to original content but does not replace it
    regionContent.doLayout();
    ...
```

`.update()` does this:

[image]

`.add()` does this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the idea about card layout, I'll look at that, but I solved this particular problem another way, see my answer below

Answer (score 8):

You'll want to use a panel with card layout:

```
var card=new Ext.Panel({
    layout:'card',
    activeItem:0,
    items:[ regionContent , newPanel ]
});
```

That panel can then go inside your viewport. To switch between them you'll use something like this:

```
card.getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
```

Take a look at the two card layouts for working examples:
http://dev.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html

Answer (score 7):

You cannot remove the HTML using `.remove()`, because it's not considered an item of a panel.  So you need to use `.update()` to get rid of that HTML, and then add your new panel.

```
// clear the html by replacing it with an empty string.
// calling update with no arguments would work as well.
regionContent.update('');

// add the new component
regionContent.add(newPanel);

// redraw the containing panel
regionContent.doLayout();
```

From your screenshot, it looks like you may have used `.update()` by passing in the new panel, e.g., `.update(newPanel)`.  That method is used to update HTML, not replace components.  To go the opposite way:

```
regionContent.removeAll(); // if you want to remove all the items
regionContent.update('this is the original content');
regionContent.doLayout();
```

Did you really use the solution you posted to solve this exact problem?  For me `clearExtjsComponent()` leaves the HTML string "This is the original content" behind, just like in your screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

```
Ext.getCmp('content-panel').body.update(record.get('id'));
```

This will really work

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved this:

```
function clearExtjsComponent(cmp) {
    var f;
    while(f = cmp.items.first()){
        cmp.remove(f, true);
    }
}
```

then when I want to replace the content of a panel with new content, I use this:

```
function replaceComponentContent(cmpParent, cmpContent) {
    clearExtjsComponent(cmpParent);
    cmpParent.add(cmpContent);
    cmpParent.doLayout();
}
```